# is there a way to get Windows to enter recovery mode and automatically execute an .exe?

Tags: windows

We have an application that performs some recovery/imaging type operations

Is there a way, from an operational Windows computer, to cause a boot into recovery mode followed by the automatic execution of a .exe?

Or is there a way to add a menu item to the recovery mode,  to run that .exe?

Answer (score 1):

Fair warning:  I haven't tried this myself.

Also, you haven't said which version of Windows you're using, so I assumed Windows 8, although [it should also work for Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-system-repair-disc).

It appears that you can [create a](http://www.howtogeek.com/131907/how-to-create-and-use-a-recovery-drive-or-system-repair-disc-in-windows-8/) [recovery drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive) that typically includes a bootable .wim file according to [one site I found](https://www.winhelp.us/create-a-recovery-drive-in-windows-8.html).  You might be able to edit the .wim to run that executable via autoexec.bat or [run once registry keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[Microsoft provides .wim editing tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766067%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that should allow you to make changes to the file.  This procedure will probably require testing and a little trial and error, though.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

I would take the following approach:

1. Create an application, name it explorer2.exe
2. point the user to different shell - explorer2.exe
3. place code in explorer2.exe to launch windows' original explorer.exe

[diffenet windows shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838576%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx)

Comment: i think downvote was not needed.